# Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined while comparing the database id with user requested id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I did insert the data to the MongoDB database and now I want to compare the user requested id with the id stored in the database. When I do that using the forEach loop am getting the error as **TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined**. I searched in stack overflow but still not able to figure out the problem. Help me to solve this issue!

Here is my code:

```
app.get('/product/:id', (req, res) => {
    MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, db) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("product");
        var cursor = dbo.collection("details").find({}).toArray((err, result) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            cursor.forEach((_id)=>{
                if (_id == req.params.id) {

                return true;
                db.close();
                }
            })
            console.log(result);
        });

    });
});
```

And my data stored in database is:

```
[ { _id: '1', producttitle: 'Levis' } ]
```

Comment: I think you are trying to get the only requested record from db, you can directly query on to get only those records not whole collection required.

Answer (score 0):

you need to iterate the result variable not cursor 
this is since the cursor variable is undefined because the task is not completed yet.

Moreover you need to access the _id of the result:

```
result.forEach((currUser)=>{
            if (currUser._id == req.params.id) {

            return true;
            db.close();
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using async/await:

```
app.get('/product/:id', (req, res) => {
    MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, async (err, db) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("product");
        try{
            var results = await dbo.collection("details").find({}).toArray();
            results.forEach((product) => {
                if(product.id === req.params.id){
                    // do something you like here.
                    return true;
                    db.close();
                }
            });
        }catch(e){
            // error
        }
    });
});
```

BTW, I guess you `find` all documents from db because you still need to do something else. However, if not, you **should** put your condition in your queries like `dbo.collection("details").find({_id: req.params.id})` .